# Webpack handlebar Register Helper

Tags: handlebars.js, webpack

I am unable to register a Handlebars Helper and have it register in time with Webpack. I do not want to use the handlebar-loader as my HBS code maybe nested in HTML and I cannot keep the files out.

In helpers.js

```js
var handlebars = require('js/helpers/vendor/handlebars.min')
console.warn(handlebars, '<<<<<<< HANDLEBAR')
handlebars.registerHelper('math', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue) {
  lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue)
  rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue)
  return {
    '+': lvalue + rvalue,
    '-': lvalue - rvalue,
    '*': lvalue * rvalue,
    '/': lvalue / rvalue,
    '%': lvalue % rvalue,
    '>': lvalue > rvalue,
    '<': lvalue < rvalue,
    '>=': lvalue >= rvalue,
    '<=': lvalue <= rvalue,
    '!==': lvalue !== rvalue
  }[operator]
  console.warn(handlebars, '<<<<<<< HANDLEBAR Math Helper shows up in Handlebars.helpers')

})

// In Template.js

var handlebars = require('js/vendor/handlebars')
  ...handlebars.compile(carttemplate)
```

Running the code where `carttemplate` expects the math helper present throws an error `math` helper not found.

I have tried adding an Alias for the helper itself, moving code around so that the helper executes first to no avail - It just does not work in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reorganize your code in this way:

helpers.js:

```
var handlebars = require('js/helpers/vendor/handlebars.min')

handlebars.registerHelper('math', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue) {
  ...
})

module.exports = {
    handlebars: handlebars
};
```

Template.js:

```
var heplers = require('./helpers')
var handlebars = heplers.handlebars;
...
handlebars.compile(carttemplate)
```